# "How to use append or extend function using def function in python?"

Tags: python

I am trying to append or extend values by using "def" function, but, I am getting an error `numpy.float64 object is not iterable`

Basically, I want to store different slopes values in the variable name "all_slope" by using extend or append function. I am passing four different values in call function that is a slope. Would, it possible to help me?

```
all_slope=[]
def slope(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    x=x2-x1
    y=y2-y1
    slope_value=(y/x)
    all_slope.extend(slope_value)
    return all_slope
slope(3,2,4,2)
```

Comment: Change `extend` to `append` and you are good to go

Comment: `all_slope` is a global variable, you don't really need that `return`

Comment: @sahaj Patel, if the answer posted below helped you may accept it:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` instead of `extend`:

Why:

> extend: Extends list by appending elements from the iterable.
>
> append: Appends object at the end.

[Read more..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python)

Hence:

```
all_slope=[]
def slope(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    x=x2-x1
    y=y2-y1
    slope_value=(y/x)
    all_slope.append(slope_value)
    return all_slope

print(slope(3,2,4,2))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2.0]
```

**EDIT:**

Good catch by @ mfitzp, Since `all_slope` is a global var, you could just call the function and then print the list without `return`:

```
all_slope=[]
def slope(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    x=x2-x1
    y=y2-y1
    slope_value=(y/x)
    all_slope.append(slope_value)

slope(3,2,4,2)
print(all_slope)
```

Comment: @sahajpatel if the answer helped, you may click on the tick sign beside it to accept it. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I can't . Because I am a new user. I need to gain more reputation for that.

Comment: @sahajpatel you can always accept an answer after 15 minutes of asking a question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

change `all_slope.extend(slope_value)` to `all_slope.append(slope_value)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion